# Why is this not working append not showing the form closed tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why is this not working? The tag closes by itself, and my closed tag is not showing up. Because of this the `if(isset($_POST['payoneer-btn']))` is not working.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Post the code instead of screenshots

Comment: ^^ -> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in HTML. But the DOM isn't HTML, it's *objects*. When you ask jQuery to parse HTML and add it to the DOM, it will auto-close elements you leave dangling (when it can) and create the necessary DOM objects. You never use *just* closing tags with jQuery's `append` (it doesn't make sense, conceptually). So your first `.append` line appends a complete `form` object.

So instead, you might:

1. Do `var form = $("<form ...>");`
2. Use `form.append(...)` for anything you want to put in the form
3. Then add that completed structure to where you want it, via `form.appendTo(inputs);` (or `inputs.append(form);`)

Comment: Can you make this html code like that?
<form method="post">
<label for="PaypalEmail">Email</label><input name="PaypalEmail" type="text" placeholder="Your PayPal Email" /><br />
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="paypal-btn">Save</button><br />
</form>
<br />

Comment: @smokzz: I don't see why not, if you mean within a single `append` call. I tend to steer away from generating HTML and then appending it if I'm already doing DOM manipulation...

Comment: @smokzz: Please do fix the question.

Comment: Im not good at jquery neither in js so can you do that html code make it work in jquery so form tag will be in its place.

Comment: @smokzz: Practice is a great way to improve. If you run into a **specific** problem doing it, post your code (as code, not a picture) and explain the specific problem you're having. The question you asked *here* -- why are things being appended in the wrong place -- is answered.

Comment: Again the same thing, form tag opens and closes by itself, i did it like you said.

Comment: var form = $("<form id='test'>");  
form.append("<label>"); 
$("body").append(form)

This would work as @T.J.Crowder says, If it is not working you are doing something wrong. To check please share your code not the image. Also please do not forget to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Append is self closing. You need to append your labels and buttons to your form, or do it all as one - like you have for your second append with the label and the input. Just wrap that in the form.

```
var htmlString = "<form><input type='text' name='whatever'/><button>All good</button></form>"

inputs.append(htmlString)
```